# How to update MySQL rows in specific order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to change the `id` (Primary Key, AUTO_INCREMENT) of every row in a table using this:

```
UPDATE foo SET id = id + 4;
```

But it's giving me:

```
Duplicate row for primary key value 5
```

Or something along the lines of that.

How can I fix this? Is there a query to update the rows in backward order, so this won't happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution to do it in a single SQL statement.

```
UPDATE     foo F 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC) F2 
ON         F.id = F2.id 
SET        F.id = F.id + 4
```

Comment: @Dynelight If you say so.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way to do this. But you could try making a select, sort by id from biggest to smallest, and modify it one by one. Once again, it is inefficient but it gets the job done.

Comment: would you happen to have a query handy that I could use?

Comment: I meant to do this not within SQL myself if you were calling from a program. Or, you can drop the key temporarily, make the update and add it again. Once again, not the most elegant of solutions, but works.

Comment: Hmm.... not very suitable for my situation, as I am looking for an SQL-only answer. A MySQL solution would be preferred.

Comment: You could drop the key temporarily and add it again. If it is a maintenance kind of thing it shouldn't be a big problem. Not a good solution if you plan to do this constantly or in production however.

Comment: My solution does what you are suggesting in a single SQL statement, without a loop from an external program

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional `column id2`, set the `column id2` `value=id+4`, and then set the `id=id2`.

**UPDATE**: or you can try to switch check constraints `OFF`, do your update and switch it `ON`.